# How to override both the json and html 404 response with springboot?

Tags: spring-boot

I've noticed the generic error controller returns the path in the response (provided by the user) in the 404 response for json and I'd like an override to configure this.

So far I've turned off the basic whitelabel stuff

> error.whitelabel.enabled=false

Then I configured my own controller to handle the /error path but ... when I go to run the app springboot tries to "wire up" another BasicErrorController causing an exception

If I want to officially override the 404 page (along w/ other http response types like application/json) how can I do this using springboot?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25356781/spring-boot-remove-whitelabel-error-page/25362790#25362790

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure your controller implements ErrorController.

```
@RestController
public class MyErrorController implements ErrorController{

    private static final String ERROR_PATH = "/error";

    @RequestMapping(value=ERROR_PATH)
    public String handleError(){
        return "something terrible happened";
    }

    @Override
    public String getErrorPath() {
        return ERROR_PATH;
    }
}
```