# How to get ErrorAttributes autowired also in tests?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, integration-testing, spring-test

This is probably quite basic, but I'm new to Spring Boot (and many aspects of Spring in general) and [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing) didn't directly answer this.

#### The setup

Using latest Spring Boot (1.2.1), I have some integration tests where Spring is loaded up and dependencies nicely autowired (it was delightfully simple to set this up).

Base class for tests:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
public abstract class IntegrationTest {

}
```

The main `Application` class doesn't have much more than main method with `SpringApplication.run()` and these annotations:

```
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableScheduling
```

Example test:

```
public class UserServiceTest extends IntegrationTest {    
    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @Test
    public void testSomething() throws Exception {
        // Use UserService; make assertions
    }    
}
```

For necessary dependiencies, I just have `spring-boot-starter-test`:

```
<!-- Typical Spring Boot test dependencies: Spring Test, JUnit, Hamcrest, Mockito -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

#### The problem

I created a custom ErrorController [along these lines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25362790/56285), where I define an `@Autowired ErrorAttributes` field. See [the CustomErrorController source code](https://gist.github.com/jonikarppinen/662c38fb57a23de61c8b).

After this, the Spring integration tests stopped working:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
    No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorAttributes] found for dependency: 
    expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. 
    Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

#### The question

What is the *simplest*, cleanest way to get that ErrorAttributes bean injected also in tests?

Should I create separate `Application` used for tests, with some kind of mocked `ErrorAttributes` bean, or might there be a simpler way? Am I missing some helper or dependency related to web/controller testing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can annotate a test class with `@WebAppConfiguration` to instruct Spring's test framework to create a web application context (which is sufficient for autowiring `ErrorAttributes`) without actually starting the embedded container.

Comment: Maybe i misuse this annotation, but is use @ WebAppConfiguration with @ IntegrationTest and a still start the embedded container. My workaround was to use @ IntegrationTest({"many other param...","server.port:0"}) and it is OK now

Answer (score 7):

Annotate your test base class or individual test case classes with `@WebIntegrationTest`

It's mentioned here:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work. (Btw, those who run into `IllegalStateException: Tomcat connector in failed state` when trying to run tests, it's probably because you have your dev already server running on the same localhost port.)

Comment: I didn't mention it because it wasn't specifically asked for in the question, but you can use `@WebIntegrationTest(randomPort=true)` and then autowire the actual port used with `@Value("${local.server.port}")
    int port;` in your test class.

Comment: Ah, thanks! In the end I went with a non-random, non-default port as in the docs: `@WebIntegrationTest("server.port:9000")`

Comment: @Jonik You can also use `@WebAppConfiguration` on your test class to get a web application context (which is sufficient for autowiring `ErrorAttributes`) without actually starting the embedded container.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson: Thanks, that's actually a better solution for my current needs! I think you should post that as an answer.

Comment: `@WebIntegrationTest` is deprecated now. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39417530/what-is-the-proper-annotation-since-springapplicationconfiguration-webintegra

Answer (score 2):

Following code is working for me Spring boot with annotation

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)

@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes =Application.class)

@WebIntegrationTest(randomPort=true)

@ContextConfiguration(classes = Application.class)


public class MyRepositoryIntegrationTests  {

    @Autowired
    private IMyRepository myRepository;



       @Test
       public void testSalutationMessage() {
          System.out.println("Inside testSalutationMessage()"+my.findAll());

          //assertEquals(message,message);
       }

}
```