# How to remove white label error page in spring boot application?

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I am running a spring boot application. When I enter the URL `http://localhost:8080` (or `http://localhost:8080/index.jsp`)I expect the index.jsp file to load, but I am getting the following error on the browser.

```
Whitelabel Error Page

    This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

    Sat Mar 05 21:56:33 IST 2016
    There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
    No message available
```

My index.jsp is present in webContent directory and my AppConfig class is as follows

```
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.test.repository")
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.test.domain")
@PropertySource(value={"classpath:application.properties"})
public class AppConfig {
    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource datasource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        datasource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("spring.datasource.driver-class-name"));
        datasource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("spring.datasource.url"));
        datasource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("spring.datasource.username"));
        datasource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("spring.datasource.password"));
        return datasource;
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurerAdapter forwarderToIndex() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
                registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("forward://index.jsp");
            }
        };
    }

}
```

I also referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25356781/spring-boot-remove-whitelabel-error-page) which didn't help me. How do I eliminate this error and redirect to index.jsp?

Comment: please post the code for your controller

Answer (score 2):

You can remove Error page auto configuration by using

```
exclude = { ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.class }
```

in your `@SpringBootApplication` annotation

i.e

```
 @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = { "com.myapp.app" }, exclude = { ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.class })
```

if you are not using

`@SpringBootApplication` you can do that by placing in your configuration class

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration( exclude = { ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.class })
```

Comment: Thank you. It helped me eliminate the white label error but I am unable to load index.jsp file which is present in project's root directory.

Comment: @Surajhk it should be in your webapp folder and make sure you are not overriding path "/" in your controller

Comment: It's in webapp folder and there is no controller with resource having mapping of "/". Still I am getting 404 when I hit http://localhost:8080

Answer (score 0):

you can add tomcat jasper dependency in your pom.xml file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId> org.apache.tomcat </groupId>
    <artifactId> tomcat-jasper </artifactId>
    <version>9.0.5</version>
</dependency>
```