# Issue with spring boot's thymeleaf auto configuration trying to resolve error template for rest application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

My Spring Boot REST application only uses Thymeleaf for mail templates.

Unfortunately my boot configuration tries to resolve an error template when an error is encountered.

See exception below:

```
21:25:30.030 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet dispatcherServlet threw exception
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "error", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
        at org.thymeleaf.TemplateRepository.getTemplate(TemplateRepository.java:246)
        at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1104)
        at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1060)
        at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1011)
        at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:335)
        at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1257)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1037)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:980)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:726)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:471)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:394)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:311)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:395)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:254)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:177)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
21:25:30.030 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost] - Exception Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error]
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "error", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:726)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:471)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:394)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:311)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:395)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:254)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:177)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "error", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
        at org.thymeleaf.TemplateRepository.getTemplate(TemplateRepository.java:246)
        at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1104)
        at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1060)
        at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1011)
        at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:335)
        at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1257)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1037)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:980)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
        ... 25 common frames omitted
```

This seems to indicate that Spring Boot has configured a Thymeleaf view resolver for pages (whereas I only uses Thymeleaf for mail templates).

How can I make sure Spring Boot only uses Thymeleaf for mail templates and thus avoid the above exception?

**edit**: I have the following line to my `application.properties`

```
server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false
```

but it does not seem to make any difference.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using this property in `application.properties`:

```
spring.thymeleaf.enabled=false
```

seems to disable thymeleaf for spring mvc - whilst still keeping thymeleaf for mail templates.

see spring boot source code [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.4.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/thymeleaf/ThymeleafProperties.java#L101).

**edit**:

Furthermore, it seems necessary to disable the default error controller registered by Spring Boot: see [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.1.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.java#L88).

One can for instance implement a custom error controller as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25362790/536299

Comment: if someone needs to disable the hole thymeleaf auto configuration (like i needed it in my case) this property has helped me:

spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.thymeleaf.ThymeleafAutoConfiguration

Answer (score 0):

```java
@SpringBootApplication(
        exclude = {
                ThymeleafAutoConfiguration.class,
        })
public class ApiApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApiApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```