# Spring REST Exception Handling FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException

Tags: spring-rest

I am using `Spring Boot 1.5.3.RELEASE` and using a Controller that takes a MultipartFile with some other information as arguments and returns a file.

Now I am facing the `org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException` when the file exceeds the maximum Sizes.

```
spring.http.multipart.maxFileSize=17728640
spring.http.multipart.maxRequestSize=17728640
```

This works well but i need a custom Response and actually the Exception is throwed only at server side ***before the method call.***

Can anyone tell me how can I define a Custom Error Handler that handles this exception and response something like `ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CONFLICT).body("size_exceeded")`

My Method:

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{Id}/attachments", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity addTaskAttachment(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, @PathVariable Long Id,
            @CurrentUser User currentUser) {
// Some code here
        ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(attachmentAsByteArray);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in your observation that an Exception Handler with `@RestControllerAdvice` wouldn't work for multi part exceptions and reason being `MultipartFile` parsing & validation step preceding the mapping resolver step.

As advised in first accepted answer by **geoand** for this [SO question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25356781/spring-boot-remove-whitelabel-error-page) , you need to define and register an [ErrorController](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ErrorController.html).

Also, note that as already mentioned in that answer , Spring Boot already defines a [BasicErrorController](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/BasicErrorController.html) that you can extend to add new content types to return a JSON etc ( since default is `text/html` ) by adding a new public method with `@RequestMapping` & `@Produces` .