# How do you setup not found page in Spring Boot 2 and Angular

Tags: java, spring, angular, spring-boot

In Spring Boot <2 I would do:

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/404").setViewName("redirect:/not-found");
    }

    @Bean
    public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer containerCustomizer() {
        return container -> container.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "/404"));
    }
}
```

But EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer is now missing, I have tried:

```
    @Bean
    public ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory webServerFactory() {
        TomcatServletWebServerFactory factory = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory();
        factory.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "/404"));

        return factory;
    }
```

but with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, that WAS the actual answer, I forgot to add the error page as a route.

```
@Controller
public class RouterController {

    @RequestMapping({
            "/error"
    })
    public String index() {
        return "forward:/index.html";
    }
}
```

Hopefully this will help, that's the way to add a custom error page in Spring Boot 2 with Angular.

Comment: Could you provide a complete answer ?

Comment: I added the Router configuration. Hope it helps.

Comment: for me this throws: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'basicErrorController' method

Comment: see this here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25356781/spring-boot-remove-whitelabel-error-page
basically u need to implement spring built in ErrorController, would be nice to improve the answer, in order to share a copy paste solution for future folks :)
//@Controller
public class IndexController implements ErrorController {

 private static final String PATH = "/error";

 //@RequestMapping(value = PATH)
 public String error() {
  return "forward:/index.html";
 }

 @Override
 public String getErrorPath() {
  return PATH;
 }
}