# Using Vaadin Error View instead of Spring Boot's Whitelabel error page

Tags: spring, spring-boot, error-handling, vaadin

I'm using Spring Boot with Vaadin and. By using the `@Autowired` [`SpringNavigator`](https://vaadin.com/api/vaadin-spring/com/vaadin/spring/navigator/SpringNavigator.html), I have also set the error view:

```
navigator.setErrorView(ErrorView.class);
```

But when I type wrong URL like http://localhost:8080/asdf .
I always get the Spring Boot's Whitelabel error page. I know that I can set custom HTML page for the error like

```
/resources/public/error/404.html
```

but this is HTML way, I would like to use Vaadin with components,
the best solution would be the mentioned error view.

Comment: You can override spring error page:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25356781/spring-boot-remove-whitelabel-error-page#25362790

Comment: If you are calling an url outside of the vaadin servlet, the error must be handled there. e.g. by redirecting the user to the vaadin error view.