# How to replace ErrorController deprecated function on Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, deprecated

Have a custom error controller on Spring boot:

```java
package com.example.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.error.ErrorController;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;


@Controller
public class CustomErrorController implements ErrorController
{
    @RequestMapping("/error")
    public String handleError(HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public String getErrorPath()
    {
        return "/error";
    }
}
```

But, when compile says: `getErrorPath() in ErrorController has been deprecated`. Ok, i found information: use `server.error.path` property. Ok, add this in `application.properties` and delete the function, but now says: `CustomErrorController is not abstract and does not override abstract method getErrorPath() in ErrorController`, ¿need a deprecated function?.

How to made the custom error controller?, the `ErrorController` requires `getErrorPath` but it is deprecated, what is the correct alternative?.

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at `BasicErrorController`

Comment: Thanks. Any documentation on its use? I have googled and in forums on examples of use but I have not found anything practical, only ambiguities.

Answer (score 13):

Starting version 2.3.x, Spring boot has deprecated this method. Just return null as it is anyway going to be ignored. Do not use @Override annotation if you want to prevent future compilation error when the method is totally removed. You can also suppress the deprecation warning if you want, however, the warning (also the @Override annotation) is helpful to remind you to cleanup/fix your code when the method is removed.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/error")
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class CustomErrorController implements ErrorController {

     public String error() {
        // handle error
        // ..
     }

     public String getErrorPath() {
         return null;
     }
}
```

Comment: I've marked mine @ Override and @ Deprecated to get the best of both worlds, fixes the compiler error now and the compiler error later will remind me to delete it when possible.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5):

```
@Controller
public class CustomErrorController implements ErrorController {

    @RequestMapping("/error")
    public ModelAndView handleError(HttpServletResponse response) {
        int status = response.getStatus();
        if ( status == HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value()) {
            System.out.println("Error with code " + status + " Happened!");
            return new ModelAndView("error-404");
        } else if (status == HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value()) {
            System.out.println("Error with code " + status + " Happened!");
            return new ModelAndView("error-500");
        }
        System.out.println(status);
        return new ModelAndView("error");
    }
}
```

Comment: In 2021, some other solutions are outdated, this is what worked for me today.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Controller
public class AppErrorController implements ErrorController {

    @RequestMapping("/error")
    public String handleError(HttpServletRequest request) {
        Object status = request.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.ERROR_STATUS_CODE);

        if(status != null) {
            int statusCode = Integer.valueOf(status.toString());

            if (statusCode == HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN.value()) {
                return "errorpages/error-403";
            } else if (statusCode == HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value()) {
                return "errorpages/error-404";
            } else if (statusCode == HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value()) {
                return "errorpages/error-500";
            }
        }
        return "errorpages/error";
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

there is an `@ControllerAdvice` annotation

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class MyErrorController {


   @ExceptionHandler(RuntimeException.class)
   public String|ResponseEntity|AnyOtherType handler(final RuntimeException e) {
     .. do handle ..
   }

   @ExceptionHandler({ Exception1.class, Exception2.class })
   public String multipleHandler(final Exception e) {

   }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but does not work. `Error resolving template [error], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers`, but need return the custom view for each error type, by example `fragments/errors/404`.

Answer (score 0):

1. To handle errors, There is no need to define a controller class
   implementing an error controller.
2. To handle errors in your entire application instead of writing

   ```
   @Controller
    public class CustomErrorController implements ErrorController{
     @RequestMapping("/error")
     public String handleError(HttpServletRequest request)
       {
       ...
       }
     }
   ```

use the below class

```
@ControllerAdvice
 public class myExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

  @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
  public final ResponseEntity<YourResponseClass> handleAllExceptions(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
    YourResponseClassexceptionResponse = new YourResponseClass(new Date(), ex.getMessage());// Its an example you can define a class with your own structure
    return new ResponseEntity<>(exceptionResponse, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
  }

  @ExceptionHandler(CustomException.class)
  public final ResponseEntity<YourResponseClass> handleAllExceptions(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
    YourResponseClass exceptionResponse = new YourResponseClass(new Date(), ex.getMessage()); // For reference 
    return new ResponseEntity<YourResponseClass>(exceptionResponse, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
  }

   @ExceptionHandler(BadCredentialsException.class)
  public final ResponseEntity<YourResponseClass> handleBadCredentialsException(BadCredentialsException ex, WebRequest request){
        YourResponseClass exceptionResponse = new YourResponseClass(new Date(), ex.getMessage());// For refernece 
            return new ResponseEntity<>(exceptionResponse, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);          
  }
```

}

3. The class above annoted with @ControllerAdvice acts as custom exception handler and it handles all the expecptions thrown by ur application. In above code sample only three exceptions are showed for understanding. It can handle many exceptions
4. In your application if there's any exception thrown it will come to this class and send the response back. You can have a customized message and structure as per ur needs.

Comment: it doesn't catch low level exceptions.. e.g. errors in thymleaf templates