# How to pass error details to model when create a custom error handler?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

I created a custom error page to replace the default whitelabel based on [this tutorial](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-boot/custom-thymeleaf-error-page.html). It worked fine but I need to pass other attributes to the page so I changed my code to intercept the `error` endpoint based on the [geoand's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25356781/spring-boot-remove-whitelabel-error-page).

Here is my final code:

```
@Controller
public class ErroHandlerController implements ErrorController {

    @Value("${terena.midas.location}")
    private String midasLocation;   

    @RequestMapping("/error")
    public String handleError( Model model ) {
        model.addAttribute( "midasLocation", midasLocation );
        return "error";
    }

    @Override
    public String getErrorPath() {
        return "/error";
    }   

}
```

Well the code worked sending my variable midasLocation but I lost the error details like path, status,message, etc... How can I bring them back again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [ErrorAttributes](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/web/reactive/error/ErrorAttributes.html) which *"provides access to error attributes which can be logged or presented to the user"*.

Take a look:

- at how the default Spring Error Controller does it: [BasicErrorController.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/error/BasicErrorController.java)
- [LogicBig - 
  Spring Boot - Using ErrorAttributes in our custom ErrorController](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-boot/error-attributes.html)

Basic functionality:

```
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.error.ErrorAttributes;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.error.ErrorController;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest;

@Controller
public class ErrorHandler implements ErrorController {

   private final ErrorAttributes errorAttributes;

   public ErrorHandler(ErrorAttributes errorAttributes) {
      this.errorAttributes = errorAttributes;
   }

   @GetMapping("/error")
   public String handleError(Model model, WebRequest webRequest) {
      model.addAttribute("midasLocation", "xxx");
      final Throwable error = errorAttributes.getError(webRequest);
      model.addAttribute("exception", error);
      model.addAttribute("message", error == null ? "" : error.getMessage());
      return "error";
   }

   @Override public String getErrorPath() {
      return "/error";
   }

   @GetMapping("/throwErrorForTest")
   public String throwError() {
      throw new RuntimeException("my exception");
   }
}
```

Comment: @Magno C, Spring recommends to use constructor injection (e.g. [Oliver Gierke - Why field injection is evil](http://olivergierke.de/2013/11/why-field-injection-is-evil/)). In unit tests you may need to use field injection.

Comment: Annotate your constructor with @Autowired (although it should work without). The code I‘ve posted works with Spring Boot 2, you may have another setup.

Comment: Yeah. I must agree. Very good points to consider in post you linked. Thanks. Its good to learn something new.