# How to replace Spring Boot's "Whitelabel Error Page" with a blank page?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

On any exceptions, by default Spring Boot routes to `/error`, which generates an error HTML page:

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Wed Oct 31 16:01:01 CET 2018
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404)
```

Question: how can I instead show a blank page by default for a certain endpoint only?

There is a property `server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false`, but that disables the error handling entirely, so that the webservers default error page is shown (e.g. on Tomcat a 404 error page).

That's not what I want. I'd just like to show a blank plain page. Or so to say: an empty response body. But how?

Because, for development and testing the "Whitelabel Error Page" is fine. But in production I'd like to hide any exception details entirely.

Comment: Are you asking, you want to redirect to your page ? Did you look this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25356781/spring-boot-remove-whitelabel-error-page

Comment: No, I just want to show a blank page (it's a REST api).

Comment: what about using `@ControllerAdvice` and return empty response if there is any exception.

Comment: Then I'd rather use the redirect to a blank html page...

Comment: Entirely up to your requirements. But if it is rest controller I would rather return response with exception message rather than empty page.

Comment: Indeed for most of the endpoints that's correct (and that's what I do). But for a certain endpoint I always want to show that blank page only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just discovered that this "Whitelabel Error Page" is only shown inside a web browser requesting a `text/html` [*content type*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type).

If a Spring REST webservice is accessed from a native client using just `application/json`, the error is translated to JSON automatically.

In case one would really want to show a blank page for web browsers, one could just override the [`BasicErrorController#errorHtml()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.1/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/error/BasicErrorController.html#errorHtml-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse-) bean method somehow.

Comment: Finally I did research for an issue which is not exists .

Comment: How to override `BasicErrorController.errorHtml()`? Any example?

Answer (score 4):

I think this tutorial describes the way to go:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-custom-error-page

Essentially you would do something like this:

```
@Controller
public class MyErrorController implements org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.error.ErrorController {

    @RequestMapping("/error")
    public String handleError() {
        //do something like logging
        return "error";
    }

    @Override
    public String getErrorPath() {
        return "/error";
    }
}
```

And then you'd make sure the default behaviour is turned off.

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.class})
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```