# Ambiguous handler methods mapped for HTTP path 'http://localhost:8080/error' for POST

Tags: spring-boot

My data is successfully inserted into the database but I still keep getting this error. It's performing okay but I'm irritated cause I keep getting this error.
**This is my code:**

```
$.ajax
({
type: 'post',
url: '/SendMessage',
data: 
{
    message_id: 0,
    message_sender: user_id,
    message_to: item,
    message_info: message,
    message_time: dateFormat,
    message_seen: "NO"

},
success: function (response) 
{
    alert("success");
},
});
```

**This is my controller:**
    private static final String PATH = "/error";

```
@RequestMapping(value="/SendMessage" , method=RequestMethod.POST)
public void sendMessage(Message message) {
    messageService.saveOrUpdate(message);
}

@RequestMapping(value= PATH) 
public ModelAndView error404() {
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("error/error404");
    return model;
}

@Override
public String getErrorPath() {
    return PATH;
}
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix= /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix= .jsp

server.error.whitelabel.enabled= false 
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration
```

**Error:**

> Ambiguous handler methods mapped for HTTP path 'http://localhost:8080/error': {public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.rtc_insurance.controller.SubmitController.error404(), public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.rtc_insurance.controller.WebsiteController.error404()}
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.lookupHandlerMethod(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:371) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]

Hoping you could help me. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: already added it :)

Comment: can you update this class code `com.rtc_insurance.controller.WebsiteController`?

Comment: what will I do?

Comment: Could you please share the code on WebsiteController?

Comment: already updated it

Answer (score 0):

From the error it looks like you have declared multiple methods with the same url 'error' or same method signature.

So spring is not able to decide which url to map because it is getting multiple methods on same url.

Comment: I don't know why is it redirecting to /error page. Could you please help me?

Comment: add com.rtc_insurance.controller.WebsiteController.error404() code once.

Comment: I'm getting org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'basicErrorController' method

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25356781/spring-boot-remove-whitelabel-error-page/31006380 see this

Comment: I already tried following the link you gave. I've updated my code above. It's still giving me an error

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the question is actually about the title of the question (Ambiguous handler methods mapped for HTTP path 'http://localhost:8080/error' for POST)

I can say that:

- Your controller and Ajax request are ok and are really irrelevant here
- There is a mapping on `/error` that appears in one of your controllers

Spring has its own error handling (that can be overridden but probably not like you've tried to do) and it also maps to `/error`, so there is a clash of mappings here.

You can read more about spring boot error handling [here](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc) (especially [this part](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc#fallback-error-page)
can be relevant)

**Update:**
After you've updated the question, please take a look at  `com.rtc_insurance.controller.WebsiteController.error404` 
It must be your controller that is not compliant with spring boot error handling mechanisms mentioned in a links above in my answer

Comment: It's appearing on every ajax post/get that I submit. :(

Comment: Check mapping of `com.rtc_insurance.controller.WebsiteController.error404` and read the documentation that I've sent :) You'll see the reason

Comment: Hey I've read the documentation and tried to update my code. Right now I'm getting a different error. I've updated my code above

Comment: so try to remove error404() method from the controller added in the question... the error should disappear. Since you read the documentation you know how to map it correctly now...