# Spring Boot in Cloud Foundry (PCF) disable Whitelabel Error Page

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, cloud-foundry, pcf

Related question:
[Spring Boot Remove Whitelabel Error Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25356781/spring-boot-remove-whitelabel-error-page)

For my case,
I disabled whitelabel by setting `whitelabel.enabled = false`, and I also exclude ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration. It worked in regular spring boot service. But I deployed the same service on PCF cloud foundry, then spring still want to redirect error to /error page.

Any help and suggestion is welcome.

Edit:
I added exclude annotation on Application, then it works on PCF.
Previously I added exclude configuration in application.yml, then it didn't work on PCF

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a separate endpoint `/error` and then handle it in the method. I would suggest you to maintain a separate `controller` infact. My code would look something like this

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/error")
public class ErrorController {

    @ApiOperation(value = "Error Page", notes = "Error Page")
    @GetMapping
    public String error() {
        return "Some Error Occurred and I will Graciously show the Error"
    }
}
```

Comment: i don't need /error . I just want to return corresponding  http status code, when error occor. There is no other way?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out circuit breaker service set exclusion property first, than local application.yml didn't take effect. If I add exclusion property in repo, then it take preference.

I feel this is kind of spring bug, since exclusion is list, it should include all items, instead of taking the first configuration only.