# Suggest a solution for SpringBoot WhiteLabel Error Page?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have tried the solution suggested in [Spring Boot Remove Whitelabel Error Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25356781/spring-boot-remove-whitelabel-error-page) but I am getting the same error. And also I have gave, 
    server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false

When I run the application in localhost, I am getting the error as

```
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
```

Wed Dec 26 12:22:51 IST 2018
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
ServletException including path '/pages/shop/templates/generic/catalogLayout.jsp'.

Comment: Share your code please

Comment: Which file's code you need? Because it's a big project.

Comment: This is my application.properties file.

Comment: #logging.config=log4j-shopizer.properties
#when running from IDE (eclipse) or from springboot:run command
#server.contextPath=/shopizer
logging.level.root=WARN
logging.level.org.hibernate: WARN
logging.level.org.springframework.web: WARN
logging.level.org.springframework.security: WARN
logging.level.com.shopizer: WARN
logging.file=/var/log/shopizer.log
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=ERROR
logging.level.org.hibernate.type=ERROR
#Default Spring white label error page
server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false
multipart.max-file-size=100Mb
multipart.max-request-size=100Mb

Comment: Your controller, service and repository class