# White Label error Page in Spring boot in spite of having main and controller in same package

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am attaching the project structure.When I run as Spring boot application it shows white label errror. Since controller is in base package there is no need of component scan too.Can some one say whats the mistake.
[image: Project Structure]

Controller:

```
@Controller 
public class HelloWorldController 
{ 
    @RequestMapping("/greeting") 
    public String greeting() 
    { 
       return "Hello World"; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: try this: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started-first-application.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Boot Remove Whitelabel Error Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25356781/spring-boot-remove-whitelabel-error-page)

Answer (score 0):

Use @RestController instead of @Controller if want to test you response output. Spring will treat this as rest controller. else, add @ResponseBody to your controller