# Completely disable Spring Boot exception handling?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm really tired of all this `@ControllerAdvice, @ExceptionHandler, DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver, ErrorAttributes, Whitelabel Error Page` stuff.

I want to get rid of it all and handle exceptions manually in the first filter of my filter chain, like this:

```
try {
    chain.doFilter()
} catch (Exception e) {
    ...
}
```

**Note:** I do know how to disable `Whitelabel Error Page`:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.class})
public class Application
```

But that's not the only thing I want to disable. I also want to get rid of `DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Boot Remove Whitelabel Error Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25356781/spring-boot-remove-whitelabel-error-page)

Comment: @MounirMessaoudi I know how to disable Whitelabel Error Page, but that's not everything that I want to disable.

Answer (score 4):

Much/most of the error handling is configured by `ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration`. So you will need to exclude this auto-configuration from your application:

Via annotation:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration)
```

Or configuration properties:

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration
```

If you are using reactive Spring, then you'll want to exclude `ErrorWebFluxAutoConfiguration` instead.

Keep in mind there may be other configurations that configure other error beans, but this should take care most of it. You'll need to debug/step through the application start process to find out where/what configures those other beans and disable that auto-configuration as well.

From my debugging, `@ControllerAdvice`, `@ExceptionHandler`, and `DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver` get bootstrapped by [WebMvcConfigurationSupport](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurationSupport.html), specifically the [`handlerExceptionResolver`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/9cc06454aa2257d693b9488ce2b32d01e708c504/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java#L934..L955) method.

As stated in the javadocs:

> An alternative more advanced option is to extend directly from this class and override methods as necessary, remembering to add @Configuration to the subclass and @Bean to overridden @Bean methods. For more details see the javadoc of @EnableWebMvc.

The advanced option is likely what you want since you want to completely take control over the error handling Spring Boot provides. So following the advice from the javadoc:

```
@Configuration
public class CustomWebMvcConfigurationSupport extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Override
    protected void configureHandlerExceptionResolvers(List<HandlerExceptionResolver> exceptionResolvers) {
        // Define your custom resolvers here.
        // List must NOT be empty otherwise default resolves will kick in.
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public HandlerExceptionResolver handlerExceptionResolver(
            @Qualifier("mvcContentNegotiationManager") ContentNegotiationManager contentNegotiationManager) {
        // Or completely take control over the resolvers
        HandlerExceptionResolverComposite composite = new HandlerExceptionResolverComposite();
        composite.setOrder(0);
        composite.setExceptionResolvers(Collections.emptyList());
        return composite;
    }
}
```

But again, as stated above, you will need to debug/step through the application start process to find out where/what configures other beans you want to disable and override/disable that configuration.

Comment: Thanks, I knew about the `ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration`. I'm looking for a way to disable "other configurations that configure other error beans."