# Reproducing SQL Exception and correct handling in layer architecture

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, jdbc, jdbctemplate

Lets say I have this:

```
String sql = "DELETE FROM "+ TABLE_NAME +"  WHERE id=?";
       
try {
    int ra = jdbcTemplate.update(connection -> {
                PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
                stmt.setLong(1, id);
                stmt.executeUpdate();
                return stmt;
            });

    if (ra == 0)
        throw new SQLException(SQL_ERROR);
} catch (SQLException e){
    LOGGER.error(SQL_ERROR);
    throw new DataAccessLayerException("Entity could not be deleted due to SQL Exception");
}
```

I am deleting a entity from table with key(id). Now I want to be able to report `INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR` to client without causing a `RuntimeException`.

However, I can't reproduce `SQLException`. If I for example delete a letter in my sql statement I only get a Syntax error that is thrown as Runtime error and it seems like I am not catching it.

Help me understand what is exactly meant here with SQLException and how do I reproduce it and report this to client without causing RuntimeException?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is wrong. You're calling [`update(PreparedStatementCreator psc)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#update-org.springframework.jdbc.core.PreparedStatementCreator-), and as the name suggests, your code should create a fully "prepared" statement object, but it should not "execute" that statement, so remove the [`executeUpdate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate--) call.

The `update()` call throws a `DataAccessException`, not a `SQLException`, so the only source of `SQLException` inside that `try` block is your `if` statement, so you might as well just throw that `DataAccessLayerException` exception directly. I would recommend throwing a `EmptyResultDataAccessException` instead, though.

Since Spring specifically converts the checked `SQLException` into unchecked `DataAccessException` runtime exception, you will always get runtime exceptions when using Spring JDBC, and that is a **good thing**, because you now won't need to add checked exceptions to all the methods in your code.

An unhandled exception is handled by Spring MVC. By default, Spring MVC will redirect to an error page. If you don't want that, see e.g. question [Spring Boot Remove Whitelabel Error Page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25356781/5221149).