# Can I somehow replace the default error controller in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I thought I could just write my own `/error` controller just like that. "Not that fast, cowboy," says Spring Boot. More or less an MRE:

```java
package com.example.helloworldmre.controller;

import com.example.helloworldmre.data.FailureMessage;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.HttpRequest;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/error")
@Primary
public class ErrorController {
    @RequestMapping
    public FailureMessage errorResponse(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return new FailureMessage(HttpMethod.valueOf(request.getMethod()), request.getRequestURI()); // very basic class with an error message, I won't include it for brevity
    }
}
```

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'basicErrorController' method 
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)
to { [/error]}: There is already 'errorController' bean method
com.example.helloworldmre.controller.ErrorController#errorResponse(HttpServletRequest) mapped.
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.validateMethodMapping(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:669) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.register(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:635) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.registerHandlerMethod(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:332) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.registerHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:420) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.registerHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:76) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.lambda$detectHandlerMethods$2(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:299) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:721) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.detectHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:297) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.processCandidateBean(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:266) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.initHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:225) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:213) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.afterPropertiesSet(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:205) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    ... 50 common frames omitted
```

I tried disabling that whitelabel endpoint. Didn't help

```
server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false
```

I also tried extending `BasicErrorController`:

```java
package com.example.helloworldmre.controller;

import com.example.helloworldmre.data.FailureMessage;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.error.ErrorAttributes;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.util.Map;

public class ErrorController extends BasicErrorController {
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public ErrorController(ObjectMapper objectMapper, ErrorAttributes errorAttributes, ErrorProperties errorProperties) {
        super(errorAttributes, errorProperties);
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
    }

    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> error(HttpServletRequest request) {
        FailureMessage failureMessage = new FailureMessage(HttpMethod.valueOf(request.getMethod()), request.getRequestURI());
        Map<String, Object> failureMessageAsMap = objectMapper.convertValue(failureMessage, new TypeReference<>() {
        });
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(failureMessageAsMap);
    }
}
```

Result:

```
2023-12-07 14:14:27.965 ERROR 6336 --- [nio-8090-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost]           : Exception Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error]

javax.servlet.ServletException: Circular view path [error]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/error] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.prepareForRendering(InternalResourceView.java:210) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:148) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:316) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1401) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1145) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1084) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:102) ~[spring-web-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:102) ~[spring-web-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:711) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:461) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:385) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:313) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:403) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:249) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:344) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:359) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:889) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1735) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

Just to make sure we're on the same page: I want to return a simple JSON, not a full-blown HTML view

How is it done?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Boot Remove Whitelabel Error Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25356781/spring-boot-remove-whitelabel-error-page)

Comment: IIRC your own error controller needs to implement the `ErrorController` interface

Comment: two things, one rename the bean, from `ErrorController` (like `CustomErrorController`), also use the annotation `@RequestMapping("/error")` in the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's important to register your own `ErrorController` implementation. Otherwise, Spring will create its own which is `BasicErrorController`. Since it tries to handle the same path ("/error"), you get an error on startup

```java
package com.example.helloworldmre.controller;

import com.example.helloworldmre.data.FailureMessage;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.error.ErrorController;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

@RestController
public class MyErrorController implements ErrorController {
    @RequestMapping("/error")
    public FailureMessage error(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return new FailureMessage(HttpMethod.valueOf(request.getMethod()), request.getRequestURI());
    }
}
```

This property is unnecessary:

```
server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false
```

The code works even without it

However, I get one small issue which is I can't retrieve the original request path. Suppose I make a GET request to `/anything`. I get

```json
{
  "message": "Could not perform the request",
  "requestPath": "/error",
  "method": "GET"
}
```

instead of

```json
{
  "message": "Could not perform the request",
  "requestPath": "/anything",
  "method": "GET"
}
```

That is, `request.getRequestURI()` doesn't return the original request URI which is a bit disappointing

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use [`@ControllerAdvice`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html) or [`ExceptionHandler`](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc)  ?

Those are the class that can manage all kind of errors

here an example:

```
@ControllerAdvice
@RestController
public class GlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> handleException(Exception ex) {
       return new ResponseEntity<>( 
            Map.of("id", "", "error", ex.getMessage()), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
   }
}
```

As you can see, in this example, the function has the annotation `@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)`, in order to get all kind of exception.
but you also can set for specific exceptions like `NullPointerException`

here a tutorial:
https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring

- PS: As security terms, be careful, do not send sensitive error (like query error) to the client

Comment: Thanks! I know that trick. But I wanted to replace whitelabels instead

Comment: @Kodigas, understand, i think that your problem is because you are setting `@RequestMapping("/error")` in the class, when you should have set the annotation in the function